# Powershell Compare text and replace if it does not meet specific criteria

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Here is a sample of the csv file I import.

```
CN,DistinguishedName,extensionattribute7,extensionattribute1
CNPTL73J79ZN1,"CN=CNPTL73J79ZN1,OU=Laptops,OU=Workstations,OU=MSP01,DC=ten,DC=domain,DC=com",tianyang.li,
USPTD079YZLN1,"CN=USPTD079YZLN1,OU=Desktops,OU=Workstations,OU=MSP01,DC=ten,DC=domain,DC=com",gary.ortiz,
USPTD07WM53M1,"CN=USPTD07WM53M1,OU=Desktops,OU=Workstations,OU=MSP01,DC=ten,DC=domain,DC=com",allen.watson,
USPTL7CC1P0P1,"CN=USPTL7CC1P0P1,OU=Laptops,OU=Workstations,OU=MSP01,DC=ten,DC=domain,DC=com",u0147066,
USPTL77BTZ4R1,"CN=USPTL77BTZ4R1,OU=Laptops,OU=Workstations,OU=MSP01,DC=ten,DC=domain,DC=com",U0172604,
U0165724-TPL-A,"CN=U0165724-TPL-A,OU=Laptops,OU=Workstations,OU=MSP01,DC=ten,DC=domain,DC=com",U0165724,167
U0130173-TPL-A,"CN=U0130173-TPL-A,OU=Laptops,OU=Workstations,OU=MSP01,DC=ten,DC=domain,DC=com",U0130173,167
U0068498-TPL-A,"CN=U0068498-TPL-A,OU=Laptops,OU=Workstations,OU=MSP01,DC=ten,DC=domain,DC=com",u0068498,167
```

A couple of things I need to do :
Check if the format of CN starts with UXXXXXXX
If it does not, check extensionattribute7 for proper formatted user id of Uxxxxxxx
If that exists, replace the CN with the name of Uxxxxxxx-TPL-ZZZ.  the -TPL-ZZZ will be consistent though out all names.

I am totally confused how to search for the Uxxxxxxx but I need something like this, although I know this is completely incorrect.

```
Import-Csv c:\Temp\Windows7_Only.csv
    if ($_CN -NotMatch'[U][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
    {
    Replace the name if extensionattribute7 contains a value of U####### and add the suffix of -TPL-ZZZ
    }
```

Here is my script so far:

```
#Create an LDAP searcher object and pass in the DN of the domain we wish to query
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"LDAP://DC=ten,DC=domain,DC=com")

#Pass in the ceriteria we are searching for.

$Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(!UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(operatingSystem=Windows 7*))"

$Searcher.PageSize = 100000

# Populate General Sheet(1) with information

$results = $Searcher.Findall()

$results | ForEach-Object { $_.GetDirectoryEntry() } |
select @{ n = 'CN'; e = { $_.CN -replace "'", "''" } },
@{ n = 'DistinguishedName'; e = { $_.DistinguishedName -replace "'", "''" } },
@{ n = 'extensionattribute7'; e = { $_.extensionattribute7 -replace "'", "''" } },
@{ n = 'extensionattribute1'; e = { $_.extensionattribute1 -replace "'", "''" } } |
Export-Csv 'C:\temp\Windows7_Only.csv' -NoType -Force

$csv = Import-Csv -Path "c:\Temp\Windows7_Only.csv"
foreach ($row in $csv)
{
    if (($row.CN -notmatch '^U\d{7}') -and ($row.DistinguishedName -like "*Laptops*") -and ($row.extensionattribute7 -match '^U\d{7}$'))
{
    $row.CN = $row.extensionattribute7 + "-TPL-ZZZ"
}
elseif (($row.CN -notmatch '^U\d{7}') -and ($row.DistinguishedName -like "*Desktops*") -and ($row.extensionattribute7 -match '^U\d{7}$'))
{
    $row.CN = $row.extensionattribute7 + "-TPD-ZZZ"
}
$csv | export-csv c:\fixed.csv -Force
}
```

Comment: Are you replacing the values on objects in AD or just in the CSV?

Comment: In your `if` it should be `$_.CN`. Notice the period. Also your regex could be shortened to '^U\d{8}' to match `u` with 8 digits at the start of the line.

Comment: Once the spread sheet has the proper formatting, I will then take that CN value and use the rename-computer cmdlet RAF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good start, though let me say that if you have access to the Active Directory snap-in you should totally use that rather than creating LDAP searchers and what not.

Now, about your comparison... As Matt said your Match should be against $*.CN. What that means is $*, which represents the current record as it loops through records, and the .CN portion indicates that it should look at the CN property of the record.

Then you can use -Match and (again) like Matt said (he's new here but proving to be knowledgeable), that can be shortened to `"U\d{8}"`.

Now, you actually want to find those that *aren't* like `U\d{8}`, so let's precede that with a `!` which is an alias for -Not. Then let's check and see if ExtendedAttribute7 is the right thing. So then this looks like:

```
!$_.CN -like "U\d{8}" -and $_.ExtendedAttribute7 -match "U\d{8}"
```

Excellent! We have our filter for the rows that need updating. That is pretty much what Alexander did. As for me, I'd go more (using your script as a base):

```
#Create an LDAP searcher object and pass in the DN of the domain we wish to query
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"LDAP://DC=ten,DC=domain,DC=com")

#Pass in the ceriteria we are searching for.
#In this case we're looking for users with a particular SAM name.

$Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(!UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(operatingSystem=Windows 7*))"

$Searcher.PageSize = 100000

# Populate General Sheet(1) with information

$results = $Searcher.Findall()

$Computers = @()
ForEach($Item in $results){ 
    $Comp = $Item.GetDirectoryEntry()
    If($Comp.distinguishedName -like "*desktops*"){$Suffix = "TPD-ZZZ"}else{$Suffix = "TPL-ZZZ"}
    $CN = If(!$Comp.CN -match "U\d{8}" -and $Comp.extensionattribute7 -match "U\d{8}"){$Comp.extensionattribute7+$Suffix}else{$Comp.CN}
    $Computers += [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        'CN' = $CN -replace "'", "''"
        'DistinguishedName' = $Comp.DistinguishedName[0] -replace "'", "''"
        'extensionattribute7' = $Comp.extensionattribute7[0] -replace "'", "''"
        'extensionattribute1' = $Comp.extensionattribute1[0] -replace "'", "''"
    }
}
$Computers | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\Windows7_Only.csv' -NoType -Force
$Computers
```

Comment: I also am going to filter it by distinguishedname.  If the word laptop is in the string, the suffix will be -TPL-ZZZ but if the word desktops is in there put the suffix -TPD-ZZZ.    `if ( ($row.CN -notmatch '^U\d{7}') -and ($row.DistinguishedName -like "*Laptops*") -and ($row.extensionattribute7 -match '^U\d{7}$') ) { 
        $row.CN = $row.extensionattribute7 + "-TPL-ZZZ" 
    }
    elseif ( ($row.CN -notmatch '^U\d{7}') -and ($row.DistinguishedName -like "*Desktops*") -and ($row.extensionattribute7 -match '^U\d{7}$') ) { 
        $row.CN = $row.extensionattribute7 + "-TPD-ZZZ"
}`

Comment: How would I implement this in your solution TMT ?

Comment: Added a line to check for `"*desktops*"` to set the `$suffix` variable. If it doesn't find that it assumes it is a laptop. Altered the `$CN =` line to use the new $Suffix variable.

Comment: For some reason TMT yours is not working.  It tells me that there are no results.  I have tested down to the $Results var and there is info in the pipeline.

Comment: You have a solution with the other answer, but it bothered me that this wasn't working for you so I updated it. I changed how it handles the property collections and so I told it to use the first value in the collection rather than trying to convert the collection to a string. I obviously don't have the same computers or accounts as you do, but I ran it in my environment and it at least spit out computer names and distinguishednames.

Comment: I did try this TMT and it worked perfectly.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand your requirements correctly:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "c:\Temp\Windows7_Only.csv"

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    if ($row.DistinguishedName -like "*Desktops*") {
        $suffix = "-TPD-ZZZ"
    }
    elseif ($row.DistinguishedName -like "*Laptops*") {
        $suffix = "-TPL-ZZZ"
    }

    if ( ($row.CN -notmatch '^U\d{7}') `
    -and ($row.extensionattribute7 -match '^U\d{7}$') ) {
        $row.CN = $row.extensionattribute7 + $suffix
    }
}

$csv | export-csv c:\fixed.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: you may have looked at the old one before i corrected it Alexander.  It should be -NOTMATCH  if ( ($row.CN -NOTmatch '^U\d{7}') `
    -and ($row.extensionattribute7 -match '^U\d{7}$') ) .  But your method works perfectly!

Comment: Alexander or anyone .. please test the code I have above.  I added an if else statement but seems to looping somehow.  I look at the .csv file it is exporting to and it increases in size then goes to zero and then increases again.  Don't know if that is normal or not.

Comment: Updated my answer again. You should move `$csv | export-csv c:\fixed.csv -Force` line out of `foreach` loop.